# Facing Issue while hitting a request using SoapUI

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

Trying SOAPUI using online tutorial, everything is setup but when I hit the request using SOAPUI I don't get the expected response. Request:- Inserting a record in the DB.      T  112  QA  29    Response:-     soapenv:Receiver   unknown            SOAPUI ERROR CODE 2019-02-04 15:23:00,829 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eviware.soapui.plugins.auto.factories.AutoImportMethodFactory at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadAutoFactories(LoaderBase.java:113) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.LoaderBase.loadFactories(LoaderBase.java:80) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPluginFactories(PluginLoader.java:141) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:104) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:54) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.doInstallPlugin(PluginManager.java:141) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager.access$600(PluginManager.java:43) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.computeSequentially(PluginManager.java:420) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:377) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:382) at com.eviware.soapui.plugins.PluginManager$LoadPluginsTask.compute(PluginManager.java:365) at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask.exec(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQkZM.png

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing this issue :

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/AutoDiscoveryMethodFactory-ClassNotFoundException-when-executing/td-p/105397